# C# - save data in file that can't be opened by user

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to store some user data locally in an encrypted file. Using the settings method is not what I need so I really want to create a file somewhere and write to it - after successfully writing it should be encrypted so the user can't open/edit it.

Later the application should be able to decrypt and read/edit the file.

I don't have any experiences in XML and don't know if that's what I'm looking for. However, *if possible* I would like to solve this without XML.

Do you have any ideas on how to program this encryption thing? Thanks!

If you have got any further questions, just leave a comment and I'll take care of it.

**EDIT**
It seems like I forgot to mention that I only want to prevent the average user from viewing or editing the file. I DO NOT want to create some high security app.

Comment: Whether you use XML or not is hardly related with encryption

Answer (score 4):

What you can do Joey is encrypt the whole string and save that, keep the encryption key inside your code, then when you want to edit/read the written data you can simply use the same key to decrypt it

The service is called AesCryptoServiceProvider, Here is the documentation 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Also this video may help you aswell https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBoGknuv7ik

Comment: Hey Canvas,

thanks for the nice sugestion. I just see the problem, that if I store the key inside my code, it will be deleted if I terminate the app, right? I need to be able to gain access even after restarting the app...

Comment: As long as your key is hard coded inside of your C# application the key will never be lost.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @Canvas: is hard coding key good idea from security point of view? not sure

Comment: @Joey This doesn't solve the requirement as given in the title (*"that can't be opened by user"*). Hard coding a key doesn't provide any security (it's obfuscation), because decompilation is easy and a user can simply recreate the decryption method. It is not possible to solve such a requirement.

Comment: Yes, the only way they can get to it is by decompiling your dlls. You could also store your security key on a web server and fire off to that maybe :) but I have my security key(s) in my code

Comment: @Artjom B. well actually he could save the file on a web server somewhere so they user has no idea a file was created.

Comment: @Canvas Maybe, but OP didn't list any architectural details about the system.

Comment: @joey Precise your objective in term of security : do you just want to hide the file content to a "normal" user, i.e. not a hacker ?

Comment: Yes, I only want to prevent a normal user from editing or viewing the file. Hackers or software specialists are not included ;)

Comment: In that case, keeping an hard-coded key within your application is adapted to your objective.